# Vector calculation with list data

Tags: r

I have a function that looks like this:

```
calc_func <- function(data, n) {
    return(sum((data[1]**(1/n))*(data[2]/sum(data[2]))**n)
}
```

Basically `data` is just a two column list (loaded from a .txt file) that looks like this:

```
       col_data1      col_data2 
1      0.005          1.921053e+01
2      0.015          9.410499e-01
3      0.025          7.493472e-01
4      0.035          6.231897e-01
5      0.045          5.354181e-01
```

So if `n = 0.5`, or something like that, it just takes every single value of `col_data1` to the power of `1/n` and then the sum everything to the power of `n` and sums everything into one value.

However, I need to do this for "many" `n`, for example `n <- seq(0.1, 1, 0.01)`, and I know I could probably just create a simple loop and iterate over `n`, and get `length(n)` values, but due to previous and future calculations I would really like to avoid loops due to speed. So is there a way in which I can use the vector `n` where each individual value will be used as an individual input in the function ? If I just run this I do get a new vector/list with `length(n)` values, but something is wrong, and the values are not at all what they should be (I'm not sure what it is actually doing to be honest).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `mapply`:

Say you want to do this for `n=2` through `n=4` and your data is stored in dataframe named `df`, then:

```
mapply(calc_func, n=seq(2,4), MoreArgs = list(data=df))
```